# How to find out which package a particular file under /usr/share came from?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

How do I find out which (`apt-get`-installed) package a particular file came from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dpkg -S`, as in `dpkg -S /path/to/file`.

For sorting list in column, Follow:

```
dpkg -S /usr/share | tr " ," "\n" | sort
```

Comment: can you explain what is tr command??

Answer (score 1):

You can also find out the package path from the package name:

```
$dpkg -L <package name>
```

e.g.

```
$dpkg -L zip
```